# Raw data approach

Tags: javascript, serialization, memory-management, esp32, arraybuffer

I am working on a javascript code that receive raw bytes and create a graph out of it. Looking for the best approach to manage such raw (mainly uint32) data.

My server (low end microcontroller) sends 2MB blocks of raw data (just **memcpy** from eg. **struct name {uint32_t NAME, uint32_t NAME2};**). I'd like concat many of these block. Be able to save concated blocks on local computer, but also have an easy way to access data via code.

At the moment I just parse data after receiving (using **DataView** and **getUint32**), adding into array (using **dataseries.push({ … });**). For saving I am just using **JSON.stringify(data)**, what is not the bast way because each variable contains also variable name (eg. *{„NAME”:1,”NAME2”:0})*. Access using eg. **dataseries[x].NAME**.

How can I do it better?

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid JSON and just use comma-delimited strings:

```
// returns String
function getArrayBufferString(arrayBuffer) {
  return new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer).toString()
}

// returns ArrayBuffer
function parseArrayBufferString(string) {
  return new Uint8Array(string.split(',')).buffer
}
```